# How to select unique rows with SQlite SELECT statement by comparing neighbouring rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, max, sql-null

I have an sqlite table that can contain "almost" duplicate rows.

where the only difference when these "duplicates" exists is that one of the rows has a `NULL` value in Foreign Key column:-

a simplified version of the table is as follows:-

```
NAME       FK1         FK2           WATCH   
AAAAAAAA   NULL        10099999        1     
AAAAAAAA   8008        10099999        1
BBBBBBBB   1111        30088888        2 
CCCCCCCC   2222        75656463        1
DDDDDDDD   3333        34242434        2
GGGGGGGG   NULL        70099999        1     
GGGGGGGG   4224        70099999        1
```

In the above example the rows I require to select are

```
NAME       FK1         FK2           WATCH   
AAAAAAAA   8008        10099999        1
CCCCCCCC   2222        75656463        1
GGGGGGGG   4224        70099999        1
```

e.g. Any row where WATCH = 1 AND where "duplicate" FK2 rows exists I require where FK1 IS NOT NULL

There is another scenario though that the same SQL statement must handle

```
NAME       FK1         FK2           WATCH   
KKKKKKKK   NULL        87656463        1     
LLLLLLLL   5454        65453535        2
MMMMMMMM   NULL        48723747        1 
MMMMMMMM   9229        48723747        1
NNNNNNNN   2765        77000007        2
OOOOOOOO   NULL        83343343        1     
ZZZZZZZZ   8118        63737422        1
```

In the above example the rows I require to select are

```
NAME       FK1         FK2           WATCH     
KKKKKKKK   NULL        87656463        1 
MMMMMMMM   9229        48723747        1
OOOOOOOO   NULL        83343343        1     
ZZZZZZZZ   8118        63737422        1
```

e.g. Any row where WATCH = 1 AND where "duplicate" FK2 rows exists I require where FK1 IS NOT NULL unless theres ONLY the FK1 IS NULL then I require those rows

Is this possible to achieve in a single SQLite statement?

I've got this statement that seems to work

```
SELECT  T1.name, T1.fk1, T1.fk2 
FROM  my_table T1
WHERE T1.watch = 1
AND T1.fk1 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT  T2.name, T2.fk1, T2.fk2 
FROM  my_table T2
WHERE T2.watch = 1
AND T2.fk1 IS NULL
AND T2.fk2  NOT IN (SELECT T3.fk2 FROM  my_table T3 WHERE T3.watch = 1 AND T3.fk1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation:

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(FK1) FK1, FK2, WATCH
FROM my_table
WHERE WATCH = 1
GROUP BY NAME;
```

When the aggregate function `MAX()` is used in such queries, SQLite returns the row that contains the max value returned.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5ac04b69f78238fa1f47a4426c63aceb).